# Nested filtering in rsyslogd

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using rsyslogd and trying to figure out why things like

```
if $hostname startswith 'd.42ba7373' and $programname == 'app' then /var/log/bla2app
```

work just fine, but

```
if $hostname startswith 'd.42ba7373' and $programname == 'heroku' then {
   action(type='omfile' file='/var/log/bla2heroku')
}
```

gives an error `unknown priority name`.

Ideas? Using version 5.8.6 on EC2 ubuntu instance.